# LC3 Assembly Programming Error: constant outside of allowed range

Tags: lc3

I have a simple demo assembly program named as a.asm:

bash-3.2$ cat a.asm

```
; demo program:

; R1 contains INPUT A, for example, x0001 

; R2 contains INPUT B, for example, #-1 (xFFFF)

; R3 contains the result of subtraction of two numbers 

.ORIG       x3000                     ; Program storage location

            LD    R1,INPUT1           ; R1 contains input number
            LD    R2,INPUT2           ; R2 contains -1
            ADD   R3,R1,R2            ; R3 contains result of A-B 
            TRAP x25

INPUT1     .FILL  x0001               ; Input #1 

INPUT2     .FILL  xFFFF               ; 2's complement of 1 (i.e. #-1)

.END
```

bash-3.2$ lc3as a.asm

STARTING PASS 1

14: constant outside of allowed range

1 errors found in first pass.

bash-3.2$

If I change xFFFF to #-1, the error would go away and the program worked as expected:

bash-3.2$ lc3as a.asm

STARTING PASS 1

0 errors found in first pass.

STARTING PASS 2

0 errors found in second pass.

bash-3.2$

What is wrong with the line: "INPUT2        .FILL      xFFFF" ?

Comment: I don't get the error.  I'm using the online/web LC-3 tooling (http://wchargin.github.io/lc3web/#, and my modification https://erikeidt.github.io/lc3web/#, which allows .FILL label).  What tooling are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I tried another online tool, it did not show the  error. The tool showed the error is the one I compiled on macOS. It could be a bug from my tool.